# C# - Convert a Type Array to a Generic List

Tags: c#

Code Snippet:

```
ShippingPeriod[] arrShippingPeriods;
.
.
.

List<ShippingPeriod> shippingPeriods = ShippingPeriodList.ToList<ShippingPeriod>();
```

The Last line won't compile and the error I get is:

"'ShippingPeriod[]' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable)' has some invalid arguments"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

try this:

```
ShippingPeriod [] arrShippingPeriods;

//init and populate array

IList<ShippingPeriods> lstShippingPeriods = 
                  arrShippingPeriods.ToList<ShippingPeriods>();
```

You need to call **ToList** on the array object not the class of objects contained in array.

Comment: I must have been high or something, dont know how I couldn't figure this out. Thank you very much ... it works for me now.

Comment: It's not necessary to specify Type ShippingPeriods. It's sufficient to write 
`arrShippingPeriods.ToList();`

Answer (score 8):

As others have said, you need to call `ToList` on your array. You haven't shown what `ShippingPeriodList` is.

However, when you get that bit right, note that you won't need to provide the type argument, as type inference will do it for you. In other words, this should work fine:

```
List<ShippingPeriod> list = arrShippingPeriods.ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

Another option would be:

```
ShippingPeriod [] arrShippingPeriods;

var lstShippingPerios=new List<ShippingPeriod>(arrShippingPeriods);
```

Since arrays already implement IEnumerable, you can pass it to the List constructor.

Hope this helps

Comment: I don't see any benefit in doing this - you have to specify the type argument explicitly, and it doesn't flow as smoothly in a query.

Comment: This is just another option, it is nice to have alternatives ;-)

Comment: The benefit is that this solution will work on .NET 2.0 as well.

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution!!!

You have to put "using System.Linq;" in the header of your Class, and that´s it.
When you put that, the array recognizes toList() command.

Comment: Your solution is for a different problem.